insert same values to a table by number of times through oracle sql
I would like to ask on how to make this happen, I have to insert same values to the same table that will create unique ID by a number of times.
  INSERT INTO EmailListTable
  ( ID,
    EmailIndctr,
    TimeStamp)
  VALUES 
  (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL,
   0,
   SYSDATE)

But I want the Insert statement to happen by like 100x, is this possible?

Use one of row generator techniques; a simple one is this:
SQL> create table emaillisttable(id number, emailindctr number, timestamp date);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_id;

Sequence created.

And the query itself:
SQL> insert into emaillisttable (id, emailindctr, timestamp)
  2  select seq_id.nextval, 0, sysdate
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 5;

5 rows created.

SQL> select * from emaillisttable;

        ID EMAILINDCTR TIMESTAMP
---------- ----------- -------------------
         1           0 04.04.2024 22:31:55
         2           0 04.04.2024 22:31:55
         3           0 04.04.2024 22:31:55
         4           0 04.04.2024 22:31:55
         5           0 04.04.2024 22:31:55

SQL>


Rather using level instead of seq_id.nextval would be a better option cosidering possibility of sequence contenton occurrence for vast amount of  returning rows.
